# Locate compressed section of executable

Tags: binary-analysis, encryption

I am playing with [Philips DICOM Viewer - download version R3.0 SP3](http://clinical.netforum.healthcare.philips.com/us_en/Explore/Clinical-News/MRI/Philips-DICOM-Viewer-download-version-R30-SP3). This viewer can display DICOM information (press `F9`). Since the displayed strings are not stored in the DICOM file itself, I suspect they are stored somewhere in the binary (standalone binary, no extra DLL loaded):

[image: Screenshot of DICOM Information]

However I could not find it using `strings` and or:

```
$ binwalk -M -X -e PmsDView.exe
```

Followed by:

```
$ grep -r Manufacturer _PmsDView.exe.extracted
```

and

```
$ find _PmsDView.exe.extracted/ -exec strings -n 12 -e l {} \; | grep Manufacturer
```

I picked `Manufacturer` since this is one of the longer string. Also I only used `-e s` and `-e l` as they make the more sense (eg: `strings -e l PmsDView.exe` and `strings -e s PmsDView.exe`). I've run `-e b`, `-e B` and `-e L` but they did not return anything.

Comment: Have you tried searching for `Manufacturer` as a wide-character Unicode string?

Comment: Also, you could check the imported DLLs (recursively) and see if one of them contain one of the searched strings. Another solution is to scan the whole process address space with a debugger ( I think process explorer can also do that). As stated by @JasonGeffner, search for char or wchar strings. If you still can't find it then it's probably concealed in some way.